# No internet connection with Cisco VPN

Tags: cisco-vpn-client

I have a VPN connection set up using the Cisco VPN Client, and whenever I connect to it I lose my internet connection.  This is the first time I have used this software, all previous VPNs I have used have been setup through Windows and I can uncheck the 'use remote gateway' box in the TCP-IP properties box to get around this.

Is there a similar option in the Cisco Client that I am missing?  I am running on Windows 7 32 bit

Comment: I got the same issue, after installing Avast Antivirus, the issue is solved.

Comment: If you are using a Mac computer, you can install Cisco AnyConnect by opening the App Store.

Answer (score 12):

Some softwares conflict with **Cisco AnyConnect**, as in my case. Had **NetBalancer** installed and it would stop sending/receiving any packets as soon as I would connect to VPN. another program that I know to conflict is called **Connectify**.

**You can refer to cisco website :** [Cisco Website](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect30/release/notes/anyconnect30rn.html#wp1578964)

**What I did is as below :**

1. Click on network icon on bottom right **→** Open network and sharing
   center
2. Click on change adapter settings on top left
3. Right Click on Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client Connection **→**
   Click on properties
   [image]
4. Uncheck **NetBalancer LightWeight Filter** or **Connectify Lightweight Filter**
   [image]
5. Click on OK and try connect to VPN now

Comment: Holy moley this works! Thanks so much! I have Netbalancer too, but would never have figured this out

Comment: OMG this works! You are a genius! what the hell is netbalancer by the way?

Comment: @Lupocci [NetBalancer](https://netbalancer.com/) is a Windows application for local network traffic control and monitoring.

Comment: For me worked disabling IPv6 on both connections (Cicso and internet connection).

Comment: I can't see any of these 2 options. Any other option?

Answer (score 9):

The nature of the VPN connection from the Cisco device at the remote location is to tunnel all traffic for routing by the remote location. This includes your Internet traffic which is then denied by the remote router.

You will need the VPN administator at the remote location to enable split tunneling. Assuming that the network doesn't conflict with your local address pattern (which is most likely 192.x) then you should be good to go.

Comment: How do I configure "Split Tunneling Network List" in `openconnect` for enable local access lan and net?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, and I tried to **disable TCP/IPv6** and in the cisco anyConnect secure connection. It worked just fine. Especially, if you are connected to Verizon hot spot that is most likely to be the issue (IPv6).

Comment: worked like a charm. I have disabled TCP/IPV6 for my wifi network

Comment: Works for me , 
Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

If your are using it for a specific IP range, you can try adding static routes via command prompt and deleting the default route. That will work but it may require a little manual route modification.

Comment: See here, I tried something like that, but it won't work so easily... maybe you get an idea? http://superuser.com/questions/380852/trick-out-cisco-vpn-with-routes

Answer (score 0):

When a remote user connects to the a secure gateway, the VPN Client can receive a web browser proxy setting from the secure gateway and then change the web browser proxy configuration of the user to operate within the organization's environment. This setting is in effect only while the user is connected to the secure gateway. When the user disconnects, the VPN Client automatically changes the browser proxy of the PC to its original setting.

Comment: IS there any way to circumvent that?

Answer (score 0):

Issue   1. Internet lost after connecting to Cisco Anyconnect VPN client 3.1 on Windows 10

Solution a. On Dell/ HP broadcom wireless chipset, disable VLAN Priority Support

Solution b. On Dell Intel WLAN chipset, update driver (driver date: 2/25/2016; version: 18.40.0.9)