# Unable to connect to internet after connecting to Cisco AnyConnect VPN

Tags: cisco-vpn-client, cisco-anyconnect

I recently downloaded the Cisco AnyConnect Mobility Client to access my company's network via VPN on my Windows 11 laptop. However, after successfully connecting to the VPN, I'm unable to connect to the internet. I have used both Internet and company network on Fedora. But I couldn't use on Windows.

I've tried changing the Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) settings and disabling IPV6, but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone provide guidance on why I'm unable to connect to the internet after connecting to the VPN and how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Ask the IT department of the company you work for. Maybe they don't want you to browse the internet while you should be working?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/118206/no-internet-connection-with-cisco-vpn

Comment: Have you tried it on a  "fresh" winbox that has no conflicting software (e.g. avast/netbalancer etc). If that does not work, I would ask the IT department.